# where do i send ajax requests in accordance with 'the rails way'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search input box for them to insert 'tags', and it autocompletes the box. This is going to be an ajax request to `Tag.all`.

Unfortunately, i have `resource :tags` in my routes, and i'm using ALL the rest actions for other things in tags_controller.rb (:index, :get, :new, :create, :update, :destroy, etc).

Would I make an entirely new controller or how would i go about doing this. Or should I add something else to the tags_controller just for ajax. I know how to do it many other ways I just want to follow the best rails conventions.

Also how do I go about adding it so it returns json in the appropriate 'rails way'?

Thanks!

Comment: The index action is appropriate for this type of call, what is it already being used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails normally would dictate that you use the index action (as you are requesting all the resourceS) with a respond_to block, and respond differently based on whether the call is asking for html or JSON.  Here's a link to the Rails guides that explains it in a bit more depth.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data